# where condition in mongodb mapreduce

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

How do I specify a condition in mongos mapreduce as in we do in mongos group function.

My data is like

```
{lid:1000, age:23}, {lid:3000, age:23}, {lid:1000, age:24}.
```

I want to emit only lid's having a value of 1000. `emit(this.lid, this.age)`. But this will emit all values . I want to have a condition here. Is there any means in map reduce ? I tried to filter using an if condition in reduce function but its not working

Comment: Provide code please instead of a verbal description that really does not tell what you have tried in real.

Answer (score 9):

You can do it in the `query` parameter. From the docs pages : http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MapReduce#MapReduce-Overview

```
db.runCommand(
 { mapreduce : <collection>,
   map : <mapfunction>,
   reduce : <reducefunction>

   --> [, query : <query filter object>] <--

   [, sort : <sorts the input objects using this key. Useful for optimization, like sorting by the emit key for fewer reduces>]
   [, limit : <number of objects to return from collection>]
   [, out : <see output options below>]
   [, keeptemp: <true|false>]
   [, finalize : <finalizefunction>]
   [, scope : <object where fields go into javascript global scope >]
   [, verbose : true]
 }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your mapping function is a javascript function.  You can make it do anything your want, such as:

```
if (this.lid == 1000) emit(whatever);
```

Comment: using `query` parameter is better, which can use some index to improve the performance.